# For Loop to iterate through different dataframes

Tags: python, for-loop

I have 10 data frames (channelData1,channelData2, etc.) with same columns. I am trying to run a loop to drop missing values from all data frame together.

I am getting the following error :

```
SyntaxError: can't assign to function call.
```

**Below is my code**

```
i = [1,10]

for channelData in (i):
    channelData(i).columns = ['A','B','C','D','E']
    # Remove missing values in the data
    channelData(i) = channelData(i).dropna()
```

I cannot find the source of the error.

Comment: I am afraid your python syntax is completely off-track here. Please check your `for` statement first. Then look at the indexing in the second step.

Comment: In general, in Python you index array-like objects with square brackets (`[]`). Parenthesis (`()`) are for passing arguments to functions - that is why you are getting that syntax error. In addition, indexing dataframes specifically is a bit more complicated, I would suggesting looking at the examples here: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you put the dataframes in a list and iterate through the list?
Like this:

```
channelList = [channelData1, channelData2...]
for c in channelList:
    c = c[c['A']>0].dropna()
```

Edited to address comment.

Comment: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'dropna'

Comment: @DevanshPatel, I've edited the code. Let me know if this gets you what you need.

Comment: quick question? Is there a way to do the same thing you did to select values from every row of each dataframe? for example for column A of every dataframe delete values less than 0. Do I add c[c.A>0] to the code?

Comment: I think this will work, but you'll have to set the dataframe equal to the modified dataframe and take the "inplace" argument out.